# SQL Altering Table

Tags: mysql

I want to do the following to my *drivers* table:

1. Change the name of the *name* column of the table to *driver_name* with a VARCHAR data type and a 125 character limit that can’t be null
2. Add a new column called *driver_age* to the table with a TINYINT(2) data type that must not be a negative value and can’t be null

Does this work?

```
 ALTER TABLE drivers ALTER COlUMN driver_name VARCHAR(125) NOT NULL;

 ALTER TABLE drivers ADD driver_age TINYINT(2) NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Have you tried simply testing your code on a non-production version?  Like a DEV server?  The column add should be fine.  The alter column should be good but it depends on what the datatype is before the modification.

Comment: In addition to what @KrisGruttemeyer said, everything should be OK (test first) if you are increasing the size of driver_name. Adding a new column is not a problem. You don't need the additional > 0 constraint as tinyint will only take values 0-255. You probably *do* want to make sure nothing critical is referencing the old field name though.

Comment: Add the DBMS you use (Oracle, Postgres, SQLite, etc) and the version.

Comment: I get the fallowing error ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
 the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for t
he right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(125) NOT NULL' at line 1

Comment: And, did you check the documentation? To change the name/datatype of a column, it looks like the syntax is `CHANGE COLUMN` instead of `ALTER COLUMN`.

Answer (score 2):

TINYINT[(m)] supports signed values (-128 to 127), and unsigned values (0 to 255).

I wouldn't use TINYINT(2) -- it implies an upper limit of 99.

You can do what you want in a single statement:

```
ALTER TABLE drivers 
CHANGE COLUMN name driver_name VARCHAR(125) NOT NULL, 
ADD COLUMN driver_age TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
```

P.S. If you can't run code on a development setup, consider using DB Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/